# Always NULL return value in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have the following SQL function, and I have delare the $row in the mysqli_stmt_bind_result.

```
//get the user number per month
public function chartwaitinguservsproduct(){
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, 
            "select 
                (Select COUNT(*)  from reusematching.waitinglist_product) as COUNTP,
                (Select COUNT(*)  from reusematching.waitinglist_user) as COUNTU;
                ");     
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->COUNTP, $row->COUNTU);


    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_close($this->connection);

    return $rows;

}
```

but not matter how I change the Database, the $rows always NULL.
Why? because of the fetch statement??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `$row` in one place (the bind) and returning `$rows`?

Don't you think that might be a bad idea, unless your PHP interpreter is *far* more advanced than the ones I've seen, and able to automatically associate singular and plural variable names :-)

And, from memory, I think you should probably bind the variables *before* trying to fetch from them. Again, if your PHP is advanced enough, I suppose it could do some form of temporal manipulation, but I wouldn't bet money on it.

---

Sorry, that's the Australian humour coming through but if you examine the [fetch page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), it states quite clearly:

> Note that all columns must be bound by the application before calling mysqli_stmt_fetch().

I'll assume for now that the `row/rows` issue was just a typo in your question. If it wasn't, then that will need fixing as well.

Comment: @user1660416, not stupid, _never_ stupid. We live, we learn :-)

Comment: I am following the flex sample code. but missing the most important part.

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->idMatchedTable, $row->user_idUser, $row->ProductDetail_idProduct, $row->Status, $row->applyData);
  
     while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
       $row->applyData = new DateTime($row->applyData);
       $rows[] = $row;
       $row = new stdClass();
       mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->idMatchedTable, $row->user_idUser, $row->ProductDetail_idProduct, $row->Status, $row->applyData);
     }